# Can MPMoviePlayerController play SMI files?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

Can a `MPMoviePlayerView` play a `.smi` file? If not, is there any other way to play this type of file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunaly, there's no way to play that format on iOS. It only supports mp4/m4v (h264) video format with AAC audio codec.

You should try to convert it into those supported formats.

Also, take a look at HTTP Live Streaming.

[HTTP Live Streaming, FFMPEG & FFSERVER, and iPhone OS 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093667/http-live-streaming-ffmpeg-ffserver-and-iphone-os-3)