# how to play H264 mpegts in iphone

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, h.264

My server encode video files (h264/acc, mpegts based format) by ffmpeg, and send to a client in a iPhonse. The default mediaplayer of ios sdk can not play those videos. How to play H264/mpegts in Ios? Is there any opensource player for ios that can play h264/mpeg-ts file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

iOS support playback method called HLS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming).

to convert mpeg-ts to HLS you need to segment the mpeg-ts. ffmpeg is able to convert to HLS. refer to 
[HTTP Live Streaming, FFMPEG & FFSERVER, and iPhone OS 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093667/http-live-streaming-ffmpeg-ffserver-and-iphone-os-3)

Comment: HLS can be played on IOS, but I also want to save the file to local storage, and then users can play it later.