# access to ffmpeg m3u8 file from network

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

i read [this document](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1) and folow instruction to genrate m3u8 file from a inpute file, a good help from [Polandeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1403885/polandeer) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093667/http-live-streaming-ffmpeg-ffserver-and-iphone-os-3) link either very usful, now i want to now how can i access that m3u8 from local network like http://192.168.1.2/test.m3u8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to install a web server and put m3u8 file into it...you can create a folder for better client access. for more information please read this page :
[HTTP Streaming Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html)